# How to get number of occurrences per column?

Tags: r

I would like to know how many "NOK" my data has per column.

Up to now I only have `df %>% count("NOK")`

which counts all occurrences across the entire data frame but I would like to have these split up column-wisely. How do I add this?

I have about 70 columns so I don't want to enter the column names manually.

edit:

```
dput(df[1:10, c("Vis_housing", "Seasoning", "Seas_HV_pos")])
structure(list(Vis_housing = structure(c(2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("0", "NOK", "OK"), class = "factor"), 
    Seasoning = structure(c(3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L), .Label = c("0", "NOK", "OK"), class = "factor"), Seas_HV_pos = c(100, 
    33, 19, 27, 27, 20, 17, 23, 10, 80)), row.names = 5:14, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible data. And `count` should not be used like that. For example, `iris %>% count("setosa")` returns the total number of rows, not that of "setosa" in the data.

Comment: I added a small dput output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is

```r
colSums(df == "NOK")

# Vis_housing   Seasoning Seas_HV_pos
#           2           9           0
```

If you want to filter out those non-numeric columns in advance, expand it as

```r
colSums(Filter(Negate(is.numeric), df) == "NOK")

# Vis_housing   Seasoning
#           2           9
```

Answer (score 0):

This will count all possible values for each non-numeric column (it is very unlikely that there are two rows with exact the same number, the result would be too messy otherwise):

```r
library(tidyverse)

# example data
data <- mpg

data %>%
  select(-where(is.numeric)) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  count(name, value)
#> # A tibble: 78 × 3
#>    name  value          n
#>    <chr> <chr>      <int>
#>  1 class 2seater        5
#>  2 class compact       47
#>  3 class midsize       41
#>  4 class minivan       11
#>  5 class pickup        33
#>  6 class subcompact    35
#>  7 class suv           62
#>  8 drv   4            103
#>  9 drv   f            106
#> 10 drv   r             25
#> # … with 68 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: thanks, but I don't get a meaningful output with that. When I use " count(name, "NOK")" the data.frame looks good but n is always 300 for each column which can't be true.

Comment: Do `NOK` instead of  `"NOK"`

Comment: then I receive this: " Error in `group_by()`:
! Must group by variables found in `.data`.
x Column `NOK` is not found. "

Comment: You count values by referring to their colum names, not by  their values in the cells.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get this. Is this an advice or an explanation?

Comment: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/count.html#ref-examples

Comment: I don't see any example there which does not consider a group_by or the like?

Comment: `data %>% count(foo,bar)` is equivalent to `data %>% group_by(foo) %>% count(bar)`

Comment: ah, ok, thanks. But when I need information per all columns, group_by is not applicable, or?

Comment: You do not need it on all columns, this is why I used pivot_longer

Comment: but as given in the question I need it for all columns ;)

Comment: Sure. This is why I used `pivot_longer(everything())`